# Grid верстка, размещение блоков!

Tags: html, css, grid

Как разместить блоки с **картинки 1** как на **картинке 2** с помощью `grid`?

Картинка(1)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Картинка(2)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: rgb(180, 177, 177);
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.inner {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 2vw;
}
.inner-item {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="inner-item"></div>
    <div class="inner-item"></div>
    <div class="inner-item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: rgb(180, 177, 177);
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.inner {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 2vw;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  <!--Сокращенная форма от 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr-->
}

.inner-item {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <div style="grid-area:1/1/2/3" class="inner-item"></div>
    <div style="grid-area:2/2/3/4" class="inner-item"></div>
    <div style="grid-area:1/3/2/5" class="inner-item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Вот что получилось:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Свойство](https://xsltdev.ru/css/grid-area/) `grid-area` - это сокращенная форма записи для свойств `grid-row-start`, `grid-column-start`, `grid-row-end` и `grid-column-end`. Определяет размер и местоположение grid-элемента в пределах grid row. Задает края grid-области grid-элемента.
Добавьте текст и задайте высоту.